# The _ClassInstance notation?

Tags: java, android, class, instance

I have an incredibly basic question, but searching for it in the docs has done me no good, probably because I don't know what i'm searching for. I've actually completed several programs but never used this notation i'm finding in quite a few code examples I've been researching.

Up until now, when I've instantiated a class I've basically done the following:

```
public ClassType mclassname;
mclassname = new ClassType();
```

But I've seen this used:

```
public ClassType _mclassname;
__mclassname = new VortexView();
```

I can't find the documentation for the difference in the 2, but I'm thinking that it has something to do with making multiple instances of the object impossible?

If you know what I should look for to figure this out myself, that would be sufficient. 
I just can't find it in the documents for instantiating classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Nested classes can be declared `private` whcih means they can only be used as a type inside the enclosing class.</s>

Prefixing the names of class members with underscores has no syntactic meaning. It is a convention from C++ (and Python where it's specifically used to mark private members) that is not generally used in Java, but not uncommon among programmers who are more familiar with C++ or Python.

Comment: Oh oops, I didn't mean for one to be public and the other private, I was just wondering about the underscores. Thanks, that notation was confusing me lol.

Comment: These aren't really nested classes being declared, just variables. The second paragraph covers the question though.